# I'm having trouble linking the css file in my html

Tags: html, css

When I open the html file in chrome or IE, the background color and font size doesn't change and I don't know why.
Is it the way I linked to the css file from the html ? Is the path wrong? Should I use / instead of \ in the path name?  Is the css content of the css file ok?

**This is the head section of my html document (notepad):**

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Final Project</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS3/css/styles"/>

</head>
```

**This is the content of my .css document (I'm using notepad):**

```
h1{

background:#B3B3B3;

font-size:150%;

}
```

**My css file is located here -->** C:\Users\m529759\OneDrive for Business\Desktop\Web Design Course\CSS3\css

**My html file is located here-->** C:\Users\m529759\OneDrive for Business\Desktop\Web Design Course\CSS3\html

Comment: Why don't download local server like XAMPP and put into localhost for easy path control?

Comment: I'm using a work laptop with very limited download capabilities. I just finished a course on html and am currently learning css.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using external CSS:

**HTML document:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Final Project</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/bhavya/Desktop
/styles.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

**Content of styles.css document**

```
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
h1{

background:#B3B3B3;

font-size:150%;

}
```

So the reultant output will be:

[image]

**Update 1:**

**I think there is some syntactic error in the path which you are using  `C:\Users\m529759\OneDrive for Business\Desktop\Web Design Course\CSS3\css`**

**DO CHECK YOUR PATH AGAIN, AND DONT FORGET TO SAVE YOUR CSS FILE WITH `.css` extension AND YOUR HTML FILE WITH `.html` extension**

Comment: @IaniB please go through my answer..is this what you were trying to do??

Comment: @laniB did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please dont forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: Thankk you @bhavya, I checked my path again and I resolved it.

Comment: @laniB Nice, but I don't see the difference with my answer, except the fact that you have made some changes with the folder ;-) Good job, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder with 2 folders in them. One named html and the other css. I fixed this by deleting the html folder and putting the html document in the folder, like this:
[revised file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlnDN.png)

I also changed the `<head>` link in the html file, like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` and it worked.